# Why did Hela and her power die with the destruction of Asgard?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In **Thor Ragnarok**, Odin says to Thor that Asgard isn't a place, it's the people. Also Hela draws her power from Asgard. So when Asgard got destroyed, why did Hela and her power die?

I mean the Asgardians were alive. So Asgard lived. So why did Hela's power die?

Comment: Because Surtur smashed her into a fine paste?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a cause of common confusion.

What Odin was referring to was that Hela's power comes from Asgard as a **physical place**. Consequently, when the physical place that was Asgard was destroyed by Surtur then Hela was (as far as we know) also destroyed.

The line...

> Asgard isn't a place, it's the people.

is meant to refer to the true *strength and meaning* of Asgard.

Yes, the physical place is no more but the *true* Asgard "lives on" in its people **wherever they are**.